# Variance and Likelihood

Tags: statistics, expectation, variance

my friend recently asked me this question but I do not know how to answer him. Could you help me out with it?

Everyday, John buys a $1 falafel sandwish at the food cart with a probability of 50%. Let F be the amount he spends on falafel sandwiches over the next 180 days.
1)Find E[F] and Var[F]
2)Approximate the likelihood that F>210

I got E[F] to be $90 but i cannot get Var[F] and isn't the likelihood that F>210 equals zero?

Comment: Let $B_i \sim \text{Bernoulli}(0.5)$ be the random variable of buying a sandwich on a day $i$. Then $F = \sum_{i=1}^{180} B_i$, where $B_i$'s are independently and identically distributed.  
Then   
$$\mathrm{Var}(F) = \mathrm{Var}(\sum_{i=1}^{180} B_i).$$  
Use the independence of $B_i$ to bring in the linearity of $\mathrm{Var}$.  
Can you do this?

Comment: The point of finding $\mathbb{E}(F)$ and $\mathrm{Var}(F)$ in part $(1)$ was so that you can invoke the Central Limit Theorem (note that $180$ days is "large enough").  
So  
$$\frac{F - \mathbb{E}(F)}{\sqrt{\mathrm{Var}(F)}}\stackrel{\text{approx.}}{\sim}   \mathcal{N}(0,1).$$  
Can you go from here?

Comment: Wait does that mean Var(F) is 90? It doesn't make sense...
In addition, how can F be more than 180? He can only spend at most $1 everyday...

Comment: No. Recall that if $X \sim \mathrm{Bernoulli}(p)$ then $\mathrm{Var}(X) = p(1-p)$.  
So $\mathrm{Var}(B_i) = 0.5^2 = 0.25$.  
Then  
$$ \mathrm{Var}(\sum_{i=1}^{180} B_i) \stackrel{\text{independence}}{=} \sum_{i=1}^{180}\mathrm{Var}(B_i) = 180 \times 0.25 = 45$$

Comment: @twenty-sixcolours thanks for the answer. I got it now

Answer (score 1):

The distribution that is appropriate here is the binomial distribution with $n= 180$ and $p=0.5$. For that distribution the mean is $np =90$ and the variance is $np(1-P)= 90\cdot 0.5 = 45 $

I agree that $F$ being greater than 210 is impossible as the maximum value is 180.  Perhaps what they are after is the normal approximation to the binomial distribution which allows you to answer questions like probability that money spent is $>110$ (a more sensible question!).
Check out the normal approximation to the binomial - it should give a worked example you can follow.